# How to read text with commas and then write it without commas?

Tags: c#

I have a txt file which contains numbers seperated by commas.

Example:

```
2, 4, 7, 8, 15, 17, 19, 20
1, 5, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 20
```

and so on.

I want to write them on the screen but without the commas.
Like:

```
2 4 7 8 15 17 19 20
1 5 13 14 15 17 19 20
```

I have this code, but it only writes out the odd lines and I'd need all of the text.

```
        StreamReader input = new StreamReader(@"c:\c#\inp.txt");
        string text;
        string[] bits;
        int x;
        do
        {
            text = input.ReadLine();
            bits = text.Split(',');
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                x = int.Parse(bits[i]);
                Console.Write(x + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

        } while ((text = input.ReadLine()) != null);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are calling `ReadLine` twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading in the line twice; you should only be reading the line once.  You can do this by either using the stored value of the loop's conditional check for the body, or more simply by using `EndOfStream` for the loop condition.

You should also be using a `while`, not a `do`/`while` in the event that there isn't even a single line:

```
StreamReader input = new StreamReader(@"c:\c#\inp.txt");
while (!input.EndOfStream)
{
    string text = input.ReadLine();
    string[] bits = text.Split(',');
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        int x = int.Parse(bits[i]);
        Console.Write(x + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if all you need to do is write it out, you don't need to put so much effort into it:

```
while ((text = input.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text.Replace(","," "));
}
```

Comment: I had to do some more stuff with it but I didn't only know this part.

Answer (score 1):

Use of streamread is so, .Net 1 (IMHO), use the file statics to read/write/process in your data without visiting any stream: [File methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.File_methods(v=vs.110).aspx). Use this line to read all data into a string buffer:

```
string data = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\c#\inp.txt");
```

Below shows how to process out the commas after reading in the data:

```
//string data = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\c#\inp.txt");

string data = @"2, 4, 7, 8, 15, 17, 19, 20
1, 5, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 20";

Console.WriteLine (data.Replace(",", string.Empty));

/* result
2 4 7 8 15 17 19 20
1 5 13 14 15 17 19 20
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Note you are reading the line twice:

```
do
{
    text = input.ReadLine();
    // ...
} while ((text = input.ReadLine()) != null);
```

It looks like you can replace this with a simple while loop:

```
while ((text = input.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be incorrect as I am new myself but you may need a buffered reader instead of a stream reader.

In Java, I would use the Scanner() method to open and read in a text file and then use a Replace() method to remove the commas.

Hope this helps.